# Pattern-lib : Which word is the ROOT(dependency parsing) of the sentence?

Tags: python, design-patterns, nlp, dependency-parsing

In spacy the start of the dependency begins at ROOT.

In **pattern.en** the same verb is just tagged as VP. If there are multiple VP's how do you know which one is the ROOT ?
Is it always the one marked with "-1" ?

```
 : pattern.en.parse('John hit the ball', relations=True)
 : u'John/NNP/B-NP/O/NP-SBJ-1 hit/VBD/B-VP/O/VP-1 the/DT/B-NP/O/NP-OBJ-1 ball/NN/I-NP/O/NP-OBJ-1'


 : doc = nlp(u'John hit the ball')
 : [ (t.text, t.dep_) for t in doc ]
 : [(u'John', u'nsubj'), (u'hit', u'ROOT'), (u'the', u'det'), (u'ball', u'dobj')]
```

What about multiple OBJ and SUBJ ?